# How do I get YouTube channel identifier from a channel link? - PHP

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to get a YouTube channel's username or ID from their channel link. Some channels have unique usernames and some channels have random IDs. Is there a method to retrieve this ID in a string format from a given link to their channel using PHP?

Answer (score 0):

The Channel resource (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels) has a id property that YouTube uses to uniquely identify the channel.

You can use the Channel's list method (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) which will search for Channels based on a search criteria you provide. One possible search criteria is a username parameter. Once you get the channel that corresponds to that username, you can get the id property from that channel.